# How to notate truth conditional functions

Tags: functions, predicate-logic, formal-grammar

My semantics professor uses functions to teach her class. She wrote the following sentence and three examples in one of her slides.

*[[**smile**]] is a function that takes something, let’s call it x, and gives back T
iﬀ x smiles.*

(note that c@ denotes 'any given context'; the [[ ]] aren't really important, but they denote the truth condition of the utterance written between them.  So [[**mi casa está en llamas**]] is true, iff my house is infact on fire)

- F :{x: x is an entity in c@} ---> {T, F}
- [[**smiles**]]:{x:x is an entity in c@} ---> {T,F}
- [[**smiles**]]^c@ (x)=1 if x smiles in c@

The first two examples seemed questionable to me: She calls them functions, but makes a relation from the element *x* to the elements *T* and *F*, but functions are 1:1 relations. But, I'd bet on her having a better understanding of what she teaches than I do.

The last example just seems odd: I've never seen a function notated that way; I've never seen a function that explicitly depend on the state of affairs in the real world. However, it doesn't seem that much different than writing (∃x)(Ex ∧ Sx), where E denotes an entity in a given context, and S denotes [[**smiles**]].

*Are any of these expressions properly notated functions?*

*Can you, and if so, how would you, notate a function whose output depends on the state of affairs in the real world?*

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The function :

> F :{x: x is an entity in c@} ---> {T, F}

**is** a *function*. It maps each "object" $x$ in the *set* of "entities in c@" to a truth-value, i.e. to one of the elements of the *set* {T, F}.

A function $F$ **is** a *relation*, but a "special" one; it is a relation which is "functional", i.e. if $<x,y> \in F$ and $<x,z> \in F$, then $y = z$.

Consider the relation "x is father of y"; it is **not** a function, because $x$ may have more than one son/daughter.

But the relation "the father of x is y" is a function, because each of us has only one father.

In your case, the relation $F$ is a function because it "assign" to every "entity in c@" one single truth-value.

About your last example :

> [[smiles]]^c@ (x)=1 if x smiles in c@

it is not clear to me what is the meaning of "^".

I've found some occurrences of it into this paper of Ted Briscoe about [Introduction to Formal Semantics for Natural Language](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/L107/semantics.pdf).

It seems that it is another way to "formalize" the application of the function [smiles]] to the entity $x$ in context c@, which returns the value $1$ (that must be an "alias" for T, i.e. *true*) when x smiles in c@.